# php: make array from pictures in a folder and display them interchangeably?

Tags: javascript, php, html, arrays

The following code is supposed to make an array from pictures found in a directory that end in .png using php, then allow buttons to change the pointer on the array and allow the page to display the current picture that the pointer is on. This doesnt seem to be working at all. Am I doing this correctly?

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<style type="text/css">
img {float:left; }
</style>
</head>
<body>
<?PHP
$pages = array ();
$dirname = "assets/pictures/";
$images = glob($dirname."*.png");
foreach($images as $image) {
$pages[] = $image;
}
?>
<?PHP
echo '<img src="'.current($pages).'" class="photo"/>';
function shownext() {
$mode = next($pages);
}
function showprev() {
$mode = prev($pages);
}
function showfirst() {
$mode = reset($pages);
}
function showlast() {
$mode = end($pages);
}
?>
<a href="" onclick="showfirst()">first</a>
<a href="" onclick="showprev()">previous</a>
<a href="" onclick="shownext()">next</a>
<a href="" onclick="showlast()">last</a>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: you cant call a php function on the `onclick` directly. you might want to use an ajax.

Comment: PHP is first executed server-side, then the html is sent to the client and the javascript handles the client-side interaction. That's the most important thing to learn about web programming.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cant directly put your `php functions` on `onclick=""` events. Alternatively, if you want to use jQuery, you could use `$.ajax` to request the values on PHP. From there, after you got the image paths, manipulate the `next, prev, first, last` on the client side. Consider this example:

```
<?php

if(isset($_POST['getimages'])) {
    $dirname = "assets/pictures/";
    $images = glob($dirname."*.png");
    // collect the images
    foreach($images as $image) {
        $pages[] = $image;
    }
    echo json_encode($pages);
    exit;
}

?>

<img src="" alt="" id="images" width="200" height="200" />
<br/>
<a href="#" class="navigate" id="first">First</a>
<a href="#" class="navigate" id="previous">Previous</a>
<a href="#" class="navigate" id="next">Next</a>
<a href="#" class="navigate" id="last">Last</a>


<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){

    var current_pointer = 0;
    var images = [];

    $.ajax({
        url: 'index.php', // call the php file that will process it, i just used this in the same page
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: 'JSON',
        data: {getimages: true},
        success: function(response) {
            // after a successful response from PHP
            // use that data and create your own array in javascript
            images = response;
            $('#images').attr('src', images[current_pointer]);

        }
    });

    // simple pointer to navigate the array you got from PHP
    $('a.navigate').on('click', function(){

        var current_val = $(this).attr('id');
        switch(current_val) {
            case 'first':
                current_pointer = 0;
            break;
            case 'last':
                current_pointer = images.length-1;
            break;
            case 'next':
                current_pointer = (current_pointer >= images.length-1) ? images.length-1 : current_pointer+1;
            break;
            case 'previous':
                current_pointer = (current_pointer < 0) ? 0 : current_pointer-1;
            break;
        }

        $('#images').attr('src', images[current_pointer]);
    });

});
</script>
```

Comment: This code seems to work up until it needs to display the picture next to the function calling links. Nothing appears inside the box.

Comment: @user3743779 so the links (`first, prev, next, last`) doesnt work at all? can you paraphrase? i tested it before i posted this

Answer (score 1):

**onclick** , uses to trigger javascript functions.

Answer (score 1):

`onclick` will allow you to call a *javascript* function, while your `showprev`...`showlast` functions are all **php** functions. They are not available in javascript's scope.

Also, in your php code:

1. You are closing the loop right after `$pages[] = $image`, I think you intend to display (print/echo) all images.
2. You don't need a loop to copy `$pages` to `$images`. You can easily copy it: `$pages = $images`.
3. You should be aware that `current` only makes sense inside a loop and you are calling it after loop is closed.

I think though, that you are confusing server-side (i.e. php) and client-side (i.e. javascript) execution environments.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is `echo '<img src="'.current($pages).'" class="photo"/>';`

This will get echoed once, no matter howoften you change `$pages` afterwards. You also can't call PHP functions with JavaScript's onclick.

*PHP will generate the page on server side!* On a fully laoded page, most interaction with the user is done via JavaScript.

**To achieve your desired result**, you have to export the array to JavaScript and change the image src via JavaScript, a little research will help you.